# Nest.js testing module, can not override provider injected into another provider, undefined received

Tags: jestjs, nestjs, nestjs-testing

I have Nest.js app, where certain provider is injected into another provider:

```js
    export class AppService {
      public constructor(private readonly appInnerService: AppInnerService) {}
    }
```

AppService has a method `publish` which calls appInnerService `send` method. I created unit tests for AppService, where I want to mock AppInnerService provider:

```js
      describe('App service', () => {
          let appService: AppService;
          const appInnerService = {
            send: jest.fn(),
          };
        
          beforeAll(async () => {
            const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
              providers: [AppService, AppInnerService],
            })
              .overrideProvider(AppInnerService)
              .useValue(appInnerService)
              .compile();
        
            appService = moduleRef.get<AppService>(AppService);
          });
    
          it('should work', () => {
            appService.publish({});
    
            expect(appInnerService.send).toHaveBeenCalled();
          });
        }
```

Above code doesn't work, AppInnerService isn't injected into AppService, instead undefined is passed to constructor. Why above test isn't working and how can I fix it (without manually creating AppService class with mocked service, I want to use testing module created by @nestjs/testing package)?

Comment: Why use `overrideProvider` instead of a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) for `AppInnerService`

Comment: It doesn't matter, it still doesn't work. I tried different combinations: custom provider, importing whole module in Test.createTestingModule and then overriding all providers except for tested one, result is always the same, AppInnerService isn't injected into AppService

Comment: `AppService` is `@Injectable()`, right?

Comment: <huge_facepalm>. Well I was just about to reply "yes, of course", but I inspected my full code just to be absolutely sure, and it turned out that I had a typo in my code. Instead of "@Injectable()" above my class declaration I had just "Injectable()". Anyway BIG thank you, I wasted nearly half of my workday just trying to solve this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For closure on the problem: `AppService` needed to be decorated with `@Injectable()` to get typescript to reflect the constructor parameter metadata. With just `Injectable()` as was there, it's just a function call and not a decorator, so the metadata was not reflected and Nest could not act upon it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue here, and unfortunately both modules/services has `@Injectable()`. Any idea of possible issues?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and both services have @Injectable() and not Injectable().

Setting [emitDecoratorMetadata](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#emitDecoratorMetadata) ts config option to true solve the issue!